# Compose LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid item size are incorrectly calculated

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Recently, I have upgraded my jetpack compose dependency version as below

```
androidx.compose:compose-bom:2024.01.00
```

After that, I noticed when I scrolled all the way down a LazyVerticalGrid or LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid, and scrolled up again, the items' size are incorrectly calculated.

[image: Before]
[image: After]

I've checked and this issue does not happen on 1.5.4.

I have looked at the release note of androidx.compose.ui:ui and seen some changes relate to lookahead but I have no clue what that is.
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/7d2af474b17108797a50ff4fe1584192ed344fb7